# How to remove element from table but keep in database

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I've created a mysql database. I am using a table in html to save data and using ajax to store data in db. Also using ajax to select data from db to store in the table in html.

Each record in my html has a remove button. I've used jquery that removes that particular record from the site but not from the db. That works, but when I reload the page, all records that I've removed come back to the page again.

How am I able to keep it removed from the page but keep it stored in the db?

I don't know if this question was already asked before. I am new to programming and I couldn't find it anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new column say name it as IsDeleted in database table sets its flag true or false and fetch all records whose IsDeleted status is false this concept is known as soft delete.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide it from all users, the easiest solution is to add a column with a name like `isDeleted`. However, if your requirement is to only hide it from the specific user that deleted the row, the best solution would be to create another table which contains

- PK of the user (like `userid`) and
- PK of the data column (whatever that is in your case).

When loading the table, you obviously have to check if the `isDeleted` flag is set, or, when using the second solution, if the user-data combination exists in the new table.

Answer (score 0):

Use a storing format to store the state of the table rows, you can use any of the following: databases,file,cookie,sessionStorage,localStorage,cache,etc